# How to merge uncommitted changes in files from one local branch to another using mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I am working on a local branch and made changes to a set of files :

- fileone.java
- filetwo.java
- filethree.java

Now suddenly it was decided that changes in fileone.java and filetwo.java is a new mini-feature which should be separately pushed to remote repo. The plan is to continue development for other stuff.

I plan to do it by creating a new local branch where I want to merge only the first two files. What would be the recommended way of doing that using mercurial?

Comment: How were the changes made?  Only in the working directory, in a single commit, across multiple commits?  It will affect the answer.

Comment: The changes to 3 files are made only locally. The changes are not committed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you stated the files were only changed locally, the following assumes the files were new files:

```
hg add fileone.java filetwo.java
hg commit -m "mini-feature"
hg push
```

This will leave `filethree.java` uncommitted in the working directory.

Instead, if you made modifications to files already committed to the repository:

```
hg commit -m "mini-feature" fileone.java filetwo.java
hg push
```

This will commit the modifications to the named files, leaving modifications to `filethree.java` uncommitted in the working directory.

Comment: You forgot `hg branch` before commit